# Getting error when create octopus release

Tags: continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy, octopus, octopack

I am using TFS as a CI tool and using Octopus to deploy my C# Web API project. Build artifacts package pushing and creating release successfully from TFS to octopus side, But When try to deploy for IIS in Assembly server, It's getting error as like this, Please check attached error log.[image]

Comment: The error message indicated that the web site "`$SiteName`" does not exist. Seems the variable  "`$SiteName`" cannot be parsed in Octopus  . So, you can try using the site name directly to check if that works for you.

Comment: "cannot be parsed in Octopus" Means ??? I need to deploy IIS web application in IIS environment

Comment: It means there is a problem with getting the variable value in Octopus. Please have a read [Debug problems with Octopus variables](https://octopus.com/docs/support/debug-problems-with-octopus-variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that's throwing that error is [this one in Calamari](https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/iis-websites-and-application-pools#IISWebsitesandApplicationPools-DeployIISWebApplicationweb-application). That function `Assert-WebsiteExists` only gets invoked when you try to do one of the following:

- A) Deploy a `Web Site` in IIS under an already existing `Web Application`.
- B) Deploy a `Virtual Directory` in IIS under an already existing `Web Application`.

Both of the above will fail if the parent `Web Application` (in your case `WKLS.Mockservice`) doesn't exist before you run that step, which is apparently what's happening in your case.

If you are trying to create the `Web Application` from that same Octopus deployment process, then you should use [this step](https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/iis-websites-and-application-pools#IISWebsitesandApplicationPools-DeployIISWebApplicationweb-application). If you want to use a `Web Application` that already exists, then perhaps you just typed the name incorrectly?